# How to retrieve serialize() from ajax call in in php

Tags: php, jquery

I want to send some data from a form to my php using ajax, but I cant retrieve it properly in my php

Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_comm').submit(function(){
        let id = 'submit_comm';
        let dataset = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'processing.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {dataset, submit_comm: id},
            success: function(response){}
        });
     });
});
```

When I print the `$_POST` in my php this is what i get:

```
Array ( [dataset] => comments=hello&issue_id=1447&url=index.php [submit_comm] => submit_comm )
```

How do I retrieve using the form input names? e.g `$_POST['comments']`

Note that im posting `submit_comm` so as to check if its set in my php because i will have a different forms posting to processing.php

Comment: Use JSON instead of serialize. `JSON.stringify()` in javascript and `json_decode()` in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parse_str inverse http_build_query

```
parse_str($_POST['dataset'],$array);

echo $array['comments'];
```

Output

```
hello
```